# Change Listbox values in new window (pysimplegui) to users can choose an option and pause the main execution

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I want an application that un_hide a new window and shows options to the user choice, the problem thats the values are populated on listbox only in the end of main executation.

Program start -->>  windows2 un_hide >> program not pause and listbox is not populated >> program end >> listbox is populated with values  :(

My goal is:

Program start -->>  windows2 un_hide >> program pause and listbox is populated to users can choose an option >> program continue and end

How can I do it ?

```
(...) #main execution

windows2.un_hide() 
windows2.Element('listbox').Update(values=keys_list)
#Must Wait for user can choice options, and listbox must to be populated now, but that is happening only in the end of main executation 

(...) #end main execution




layout2 = [[sg.Text('The second window')],
          [sg.Listbox(values=["none"], select_mode='extended', key='listbox', size=(30, 6))],
          [sg.Button('save', button_color=('black', 'white'),  visible=True ), ]]
windows2 = sg.Window('Second Window', layout2, finalize=True)
windows2.hide()
```

Comment: Can you pass the value of list to a fuction which create `window2` when necessary ? not to create it the hide it in the beginning.

Comment: @JasonYang  Yeah I can  do "def make_win2(keys_list):" function, and call    make_win2("exemple_list"), but the listbox still is populated only in the end all of execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example how I use function to create a popup and return the selection to main window.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def popup(key):
    sg.theme('DarkGreen3')
    layout = [
        [sg.Listbox(food[key], size=(30, 3), enable_events=True, key='-GOODS-')],
        [sg.Button("Cancel")],
    ]
    window = sg.Window(key, layout, modal=True)
    while True:

        event, values = window.read()

        if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Cancel'):
            result = None
            break
        elif event == '-GOODS-':
            result = values[event][0]
            break

    window.close()
    return result

food = {
    'Fruit'     : ['Apple','Bananas','Oranges','Mangoes'],
    'Vegetable' : ['Kale', 'Cabbage', 'Celery', 'Asparagus', 'Lettuce'],
    'Meat'      : ['Pork', 'Beef', 'Mutton', 'Veal', 'Vension'],
}

font = ("Courier New", 11)
sg.theme('DarkBlue3')
sg.set_options(font=font)

layout = [
    [sg.Listbox(list(food.keys()), size=(30, 3), enable_events=True, key='-CATEGORY-')],
    [sg.VPush()],
    [sg.StatusBar('', size=(0, 1), key='-STATUS-')],
]

window = sg.Window('Food', layout, size=(640, 480))

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == '-CATEGORY-':
        key = values[event][0]
        goods = popup(key)
        if goods:
            window['-STATUS-'].update(f'{key} - {goods}')
        else:
            window['-STATUS-'].update('')

window.close()
```

Comment: thanks!! using your example works everything as Planned :) Problem solved